# Naming and writing different files in a for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, file-io, networkx

I have what I think is a basic python error. I am building several graphs with the networkx module, and I need to write their edgelists in different gexf files (for gephi). Since I have to perform these operations multiple times I am doing this in a `for` loop, and I get an error while writing the files.

I need a graph (therefore, a different output file) for each element of the `owner` column of a dataframe.

```
for owner in df.owner.unique():
    sdf=df[df['owner']==owner]
    sG=nx.Graph()
    sG.add_nodes_from(sdf['col1'])
    sG.add_nodes_from(sdf['col2'])
    i=0
    while i < len(sdf):
        sG.add_edge(sdf.iloc[i,0],sdf.iloc[i,1], weight=sdf.iloc[i,2])
        i+=1
    with open('com_{}.gexf'.format(owner),'x') as f:
        nx.write_gexf(sG,f)
```

On the first iteration I get a

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

error, suggesting that this is not the right way to create, name and write the files in a loop. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the value of `owner` when the exception occurs? Wild guess: if it contains a slash, for example "foo/bar", then open will first try to navigate to directory `com_foo` before creating file `bar.gexf`. If com_foo doesn't exist, then this exception will occur.

Comment: yep you're right, there's a slash, I totally missed it. I'll change this and see if it works.

Comment: ok, issue solved. Thanks a lot, write a proper answer if you want so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `owner` contains a slash, for example "foo/bar", then `open` will first try to navigate to directory `com_foo` before creating file `bar.gexf`. If `com_foo` doesn't exist, then this exception will occur.

One possible solution is to replace all slashes in `owner` with a less objectionable character.

```
with open('com_{}.gexf'.format(owner.replace("/", "_")),'x') as f:
```